# Live streaming model of a person in a VR environment

Tags: camera, kinect, live-streaming, virtual-reality

Given that a user is static in a VR environment, which of the two camera types below would be better to create a more 'real' looking representation of an live-streamed presenter in the VR world?

1) Kinect (can measure depth)
2) Normal 2D camera such as a high end webcam (maybe something like the pointgrey Flea3) (software assisted 3D illusion from a static angle)

Would be grateful if anyone with any experience with the relevant technologies or fields would be able to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks the necessary information to provide a single correct answer. Is it your intent to provide a full 3D VR experience, or are you content with just 2D content? Is the presenter static, or are they moving around the viewer? Towards them? Away from them? Will you be using full spherical projection or something less complete, like cylindrical projection? And what sort of lighting do you think you'll need? These are all nontrivial questions, because the answers determine the best camera package to get your content.

You also fail to consider capturing with a 360º camera, which would be advantageous if the presenter is indeed moving around in the 360º space. My personal bias is towards capturing with these, but there's no single production solution unless you constrain the problem more thoroughly.

Comment: just flag for broad or unclear in cases like this. It's hard to find the answer in your extended comment.

Comment: the goal was to outline the advantages of each approach (and to point out that poster had missed one option). But flagged nonetheless.